# Linear regression for time series

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am pretty new to Machine Learning and have some confusion, so sorry for trivial question.
I have time series data set, very simple with two columns - Date and Price. I'm predicting the price and want to add some features to my model like moving average for last 10 days.  If I split dataset learn:validation 80:20. For the first 80 days I can calculate moving avergage. What about my validation set? Should I use predicted value as input for moving average? Are there ready implementation for such a solution? I'm using python scikit-learn library.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you have 100 days of data in a time series? And you want to do a linear regression between moving average of the last 10 days against the price of today?

Comment: Yes. But want to split dataset to learn and validation. So it will learn on 80 days.

Comment: Do you have a link to the data, or you want me to manufacture some as an example?

Comment: Don't have an example. I think simillar dataset will be date and stock price.

Comment: I'll be back soon with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is a solution using 250 data points of GOOG stock Close historical data. I have explained the code with comments. Please feel free to ask if there is something vague in there. As you can see, I use pandas and within that library is a convenience function "rolling" that computes, among other things, rolling means. I split the data set by hand, but it can also be done by e.g. sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

# Read data from file
df = pd.read_csv("GOOG.csv")

# Calculate 10 day rolling mean and drop first 10 rows because we cannot calculate rolling mean for them
# shift moves the averages one step ahead so day 10 gets moving average of days 0-9, etc...
df["Rolling_10d_close"] = df['Close'].rolling(10).mean().shift(1)
df = df.dropna()

# Split data into training and validation sets
training_last_row = int(len(df) * 0.8)
training_data = df.iloc[:training_last_row]
validation_data = df.iloc[training_last_row:]

# Train model on training set of data
x = training_data["Rolling_10d_close"].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
y = training_data["Close"].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)

reg = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
print(reg.coef_, reg.intercept_)
# prints [[0.95972717]] [4.14010503]

# Test the performance of predictions on the validation data set
x_pred = validation_data["Rolling_10d_close"].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
y_pred = validation_data["Close"].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)

print(reg.score(x_pred, y_pred))
# prints 0.02467230502090556
```

Answer (score 0):

interesting question. It seems like you are creating an autoregressive model, i.e. a model that predicts future values based on previous predictions. As such, you are right in concluding that in the validation set you will need to compute the previous ten-day moving average on the prediction. As far as I know, there is no built-in functionality to do this. It should however not be too difficult to implement. Maybe something like this would work.

```
s = list(range(80))
predictions = []
for i in range(20):
    ten_day = sum(s[-10:])/10
    pred = predict(ten_day)
    predictions.append(pred)
    s.append(pred)
```

But I advise you to Google autoregressive models to get some more insight. Also you could have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/346918 to get some info on how to split the data.

Comment: Thank you! That was my idea excatly, but started to doubt if it's correct and if i should do it by hand. If I build some polynomial LR model, the story is the same. I have to predict one value at the time, right?

Comment: Well in general, if your current prediction relies on the target variable in the past, yes you will need to predict it one by one. But do note that during training this is of course not necessary since you already know the target variable.

Comment: A small addition I forgot is that you could potentially use the previous ten "true" values in the validation set depending on what claim you want to make. E.g. if all you want to do in "production" is predict the value of the next day this would potentially be OK.